# Confusing problem >> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:

Tags: python

**This problem puzzled me.
Maybe the problem is in the code, I hope you take a look**

```
        with open(training_images_labels_path,'r') as file:
            lines = file.readlines()
```

**He says that the file does not exist**

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\Desktop\\project\\data\\generated\\training_images_labels.txt'
```

**Though the file exists**

I need solutions

Comment: On linux: seems like a very unusual path and the slashes are the wrong way, on windows: no drive letter? Also, its very unlikely that it's `C:\Desktop\...` since starting with `\\` indicates a root directory. Double check that this path really exists.

Comment: Are you on iOS, Windows or Linux ????

Comment: I am on Windows

Comment: If you are using a text editor or something like VS Code, try to run the code in IDLE. Don't know why, but it works

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If it  says that the file does not exist though the file exists, it means the path has been not given properly. Try giving the path correctly.

**Method 1:**

Giving correct path `'C:\\Users\\Public\\Desktop\\project\\data\\generated\\training_images_labels.txt'`  or

`'C:\\Users\\<insert your username>\\Desktop\\project\\data\\generated\\training_images_labels.txt'` is your path if I guess correctly

**Method 2:**

Using os module ( Recommended )

```
mydir = 'C:/Users/Public/Desktop/project/data/generated'
myfile = 'training_images_labels.txt'
training_images_labels_path = os.path.join(mydir, myfile)

with open(training_images_labels_path,'r') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
```

**Method 3:**

You can also try changing the working directory to the location where your data is present. ie `Desktop>project>data>generated` here and open the file with file name. ie

```
with open('training_images_labels.txt','r') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
```

Comment: In windows you can use the USERPROFILE environment variable. 
mydir = ' %userprofile%/Desktop/project/data/generated'

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with importing an excel file, which of course exists in the same directory with my .py file. The chosen solution above did not help me, and actually I didn't understand those three methods, as I am working on mac OS.

This method worked for me: in Spyder, I usually run the file by pressing the keys "Shift + Enter", which in this case made the problem. So, my solution was, to press on the "Run file" button (or the fn+F5 key) instead.

Maybe someone wants to explain the difference.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like its a windows path you are working and i believe path really thrown in the error is wrong when compared to the actual where the txt file resides.. just cross check once, if that's the case try to pass the correct path in to the variable "training_images_labels_path"

Comment: The path is correct, but try to renew the path and transfer files to a third party with the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Can you tell how you created this path.Some advise.
use path separator library to generate path to avoid this error.

```
training_images_labels_path
```

further try to navigate parent directory using python and print pth.may be some new line or linux/windwos convereted path or other special character in path. `navigating parent directory and listing will solve`

if still not solve try to navigatep `parent-parent dir` and print path

try hard

Answer (score 0):

Watch your path if its correct or not. I had the same problem and it turned out i didnt had the good path set

Comment: Welcome to SO! Before answering old question please check if it already has an accepted answer (this is the case here). If so, ask yourself: Does your answer provide a _substantial_ improvement or something entirely new? If not, don't answer.