# Video Upload in Cloud Run Flask Application is Giving No such file or directory

Tags: python, html, flask, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run

I am having a web application running locally on my laptop. Below is the python code snippet that takes the video from the HTML and uploads it to Cloud Storage:

```
@app.route('/' , methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def index():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        video = request.form['video']
        video2 = request.form['video2']
        
        if not video:
            flash('please upload your answer first')
        if not video2:
            flash('please upload your answer first')
        else:
            #store video to GCS
            video_list = [video,video2]
            for i in range(len(video_list)):
                upload_video_to_gcs(video_list[i],i)

def upload_video_to_gcs(video,video_num):
    # Setting credentials using the downloaded JSON file
    client = storage.Client.from_service_account_json(json_credentials_path='sa-credentials.json')
    # Creating bucket object
    bucket = client.get_bucket('bucket_name')
    # Name of the destination file in the bucket
    gcs_file_name = "".join(("video","_",str(video_num)))
    object_name_in_gcs_bucket = bucket.blob(gcs_file_name)
    object_name_in_gcs_bucket.upload_from_filename(video)
    return 1
```

It is working fine when running it locally on my laptop, in which the video is located in the same folder as the python file.
However, when I deployed this web application on GCP Cloud Run(the video is no more existing in the same folder of the python file), I am getting the below error:

```
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'sample_video.mp4'
```

Do you have any idea how to upload the video(existing anywhere on my laptop) through the web service hosted on Cloud Run on GCP.

Comment: Where is the code where you download the video from your post request? Do you save it locally?

Answer (score 0):

The `Python FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory` error is often raised by the os library. This error tells you that you are trying to access a file or folder that does not exist. To fix this error, check that you are referring to the right file or folder in your program.

Here is a [similar case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60635464/confusing-problem-filenotfounderror-errno-2-no-such-file-or-directory) that was fixed by providing the correct path.